# How to know status of the in app purchase, if user cancels it

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I've created an app on both platform on iOS and Android.

In android we have used Mollie SDK to collect payment for subscription.

In iOS we have user in-app purchase for the subscription(1-month auto-renewable).

The question is...

The iOS user subscribed for 1-month and I got the receipt sending it to server to store it. After 15-days user cancels it so now user is able to use app for next remaining 15-days of month and after that the subscription will not be renewed automatically.

So when user cancels the subscription then how do we know that that the user cancelled the subscription.

After 1-month iOS user uses Android device to logged in. Since user's subscription is expired so how to restrict the user to access app's premium content.

> I've also came to know that we can set **Subscription Status URL** on App Store connect to get the status of the iAP, so I've set it but did not get any log on that URL(I an using Sandbox URL).

[image]

**The main goal is that I want to restrict user whose subscription is expired & did not renew whenever user use iOS/ADR app.**

I'm able to managed from android side not how to manage it from iOS side?

Any help!!

Comment: You can use the server status URL and/or you can rely on the receipt refresh from the iOS app.  If you don't want to use the server status URL then you could detect that their subscription is managed by iOS (Set a flag on their account) and if they log in on an Android device, show a message prompting them to log in to their iOS device to update their subscription status.  Did the URL you entered comply with the [requirements](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/enabling_server-to-server_notifications)

Comment: Thanks for the your reply @Paulw11. Your hit is enough for me :D

Comment: More info in this answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53773813/iap-in-cross-platform/53808664#53808664